# Arduino custom-made function is not working

Tags: arduino

I wrote my own Arduino function in order to measure the heart rate. But when it executes it does not work properly. In order to calculate heart rate, I have to do the following calculation:

```
heart_Rate = 60000/period;
```

But I realized that the period value keeps accumulating. As a result of that the heart rate reduces. But when I test this without making function (inside void loop) it's working perfectly.

This is my Arduino code:

```
int H_val = 0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

float HeartRate() {
  int threshold = 750;
  int raw_ecg = 0;
  int E_input = 0;
  float period = 0;
  unsigned long p_time = 0;
  unsigned long c_time = 0;
  int H_rate;
  int oldvalue = 0;

  oldvalue = raw_ecg;
  raw_ecg = 0;
  raw_ecg = analogRead(A0);
  if (oldvalue < threshold && raw_ecg >= threshold) {
    p_time = c_time;
    c_time = millis();
    period = c_time - p_time;
  }

  if (period <= 0) {
    int H_rate = 0;
  } else {
    int H_rate = 60000 / period;
    return H_rate;
  }
  delay(2);
}

void loop() {
  H_val = HeartRate();
  Serial.println(H_val);
}
```

How do I prevent the period from accumulating?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call the function, the local variables get initialized again. In your code this means that

```
p_time = c_time; //c_time = 0
c_time = millis();
period = c_time - p_time;
```

Hence, period will increase as `millis()` is increasing.

If you declare the variables as static, your problem will be solved:

```
static unsigned long p_time = 0;
static unsigned long c_time = 0;
```

By doing that, the variables keep existing (and keep their value) between function calls and keep their local scope.

The reason it is working inside the loop is that you never leave the loop and the variables never get re-initialized.

Edit: it's enough to declare `c_time` as static as you assign it's value to p_time anyway. But there are various ways to shorten the code.

Answer (score -1):

It can be a problem of data type. Changing that variables to float or int may solve the problem.

```
float H_val;

float HeartRate(){
    float H_rate;
    return H_rate;
}

void loop(){
    H_val = HeartRate();
}
```

Comment: Why in the world would you define the function to return a float and then write the code in it to return an int?  The return type of a function should really match with the type of the thing it actually returns.

Comment: Sorry, I was remarking the error in the code from Imesh Nirangana but I see it can be misunderstood. I change it to give the solution.